# Changing the URL has no effect on JSON Returned DjangoRest Framerwork

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am trying to filter a list of my customers stored and return a specific one
when I try (xxx/api/customers/fred) it returns all customers and whatever is entered after the customers/ has no effect on the JSON returned

Views

```
class CustomerListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

class CustomerRetrieveAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    lookup_field= "name"
```

Serializers

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer 

        fields = ['name' , 'address', 'phonenumber']
```

Urls

```
url(r'^api/customers/', views.CustomerListAPIView.as_view(), name = "customer_list"),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.CustomerRetrieveAPIView.as_view(), name='retrieve'),
```

ive also tried to override def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs): but this method doesn't seem to get triggered when a url is entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put more detailed urls before more general to avoid ambiguity, add $ to the end of `customer_list` URL pattern, add missing prefix to `retrieve` URL pattern:

```
url(r'^api/customers/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.CustomerRetrieveAPIView.as_view(), name='retrieve'),
url(r'^api/customers/$', views.CustomerListAPIView.as_view(), name = "customer_list"),
```

all of your requests were handled by first pattern - because both (list and detail) URLs start with `api/customers/`.